# Custom Item Template for ComboBox Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I had the following XAML looking just as I want it to look. It's basically a dropdown menu with checkboxes and some text to them.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox">
  <ComboBoxItem><CheckBox>WeeHee</CheckBox></ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem><CheckBox>BuuHuu</CheckBox></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Then I learned that the options are possible to be dynamically adapted so I changed the markup and bound the combobox to an array. That works perfectly well **functionality-wise** but now I get only the names of the options, while the checkboxes are gone.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AllKinds}">
</ComboBox>
```

So I'm looking for a way to create a custom item for populating the combobox **but still** so that the data is dynamically bound. I'm assuming WPF/XAML supports such functionality and I'm just too ignorant to know what to google for.

So my request is a rudimentary example **or** suggestion on what to google for. (Might be something seemingly obvious to everybody but me.)

Comment: You'll just use ComboBox.ItemTemplate the same way you would for like an ItemsControl.ItemTemplate since that's all that's supplying your ComboBoxItem's anyway. There's a bunch of [different tutorials](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/) for the databinding side of it, easy peasy.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't use it like *ItemsControl.ItemTemplate*. That's because I wasn't aware of the **templates** to begin with! Now, that I just learned about it, it turned out to be easily resolved. Was really smooth, too. Thanks! Please post it as a reply so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten WPF offers quite a lot of things to learn. In case you are considering to read a comprehensive book, I'd recommend "WPF Unleashed" by Adam Nathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with most of the controls that offer up things from ItemSource there's a nifty built in feature that allows you to specify how each item should look/behave etc. So you can specify each Item in your ComboBox's by setting your own ItemTemplate.

Since a ComboBox just uses an ItemsControl to list its items, you can utilize this via ComboBox.ItemTemplate to make your items however you like, in this case probably something like (in pseudo).

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps, its some pretty handy info to know for when you want to start customizing Item generated lists between wpf, silverlight, wp, win-rt, etc. Cheers!

Comment: You'll get +1 for the clean sample as soon as SO lets me (apparently, I've been generous giving away votes today.

Comment: Hah no worries, just glad you got your remedy and who doesn't like learning something new? +1 already to you as well, cheers